# Appending list variable declared in class

Tags: python-3.x

I am trying to append data list as following

```
class Message:
    def __init_(self):
        self.header = 0
        self.process= 0
        self.status= 0
        self.datasize= 0
        self.data= []
        self.lrc= 0

    def append(self, byte):
        return self.data.append(byte)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    flagsbyte = 5
    CurrentTxMsg = Message()
    CurrentTxMsg.append(flagsbyte)
```

However, I keep getting the error `Message has no attribute data`. I can't figure out why

Comment: Typo: your init needs two underscores per side. Your initializer isn't running as a result.

Comment: You're missing a `_` - the method needs to be named `__init__`.

Comment: oh wow. Thanks!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
   class Message:
        def __init__(self):
            self.header = 0
            self.process= 0
            self.status= 0
            self.datasize= 0
            self.data= []
            self.lrc= 0

        def append(self, byte):
            return self.data.append(byte)

    if __name__ == '__main__':
        flagsbyte = 5
        CurrentTxMsg = Message()
        CurrentTxMsg.append(flagsbyte)
```

just replace  **__init_  to  __init__**